# How can I force VS Code to debug as sudo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

This is the content of my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/Crm/AdminApi/Api.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": ""
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "/Crm/AdminApi/Api.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": ""
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "/Crm/AdminApi/Api.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that when I run it using <kbd>F5</kbd> it fails because it runs as the `vscode` user I guess.

Also when I run `dotnet build` from inside the VS Code terminal, it does not work.

However, when I run `sudo dotnet build` in the VS Code terminal, or when I run `dotnet build` from a root bash terminal, it works.

How can I force VS Code to run my code as the root user? I tried `"command": "sudo dotnet"` but it did not work.

Comment: by running VSCode with sudo ? then all commands executed by VSCode would be using same user context ... (yeah, security... but if you really need to debug ...)

Comment: To answer your question - did you try to run vscode as SU? try to open it as super user. To the super user issue - I dont know what is the exact problem here that prevents you from running the code as presented, but it sounds that something is wrong. Sounds like the SU issue is a wrong and dangerous bypass.

Comment: @Selvin have you tried to run vs code as root on Linux (Ubuntu) ever? try it. It needs to be like `sudo code /path/to/project --no-sandbox --user-data-dir` and then it only shows a blank screen. I would love to always run VS Code as root.

Comment: Why do you want to run it as sudo? What errors/problems are you facing, when run normally? Ports not accessible or file read/write issues?

Comment: @nilsK as I mentioned in the question it's because it does not work. It does not build the project.

Comment: 'it does not work' is not helping ;) What does this mean? Errors/Exceptions? What is not working? Be more precisely, please.

Comment: @nilsK it hangs for a long time. And it tries to download packages again while they are already restored. And at last it throws the exception that something related to NuGet is locked by another user.

Comment: Try `dotnet clean`, then, manually, delete all `obj` and `bin` folders for every project in your solution. Run `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` to make sure, that you pull the right NuGet packages. If 'NuGet is locked...' error keeps coming, a restart of your computer might already help. Do you have a Visual Studio or different IDE running in parallel? Are you restoring with `dotnet restore -f`? The `-f` *forces* a fresh download, even when already downloaded/cached.